# How to report the progress of a method of a class

Tags: c#

How can I report real-time progress of a method within a class?

```
public class Foo{
    public string Bar(){
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            i++;
            //return i.ToString();
            if(i > 10) break;
        }
        return "Loop end";
    }
}


Foo foo = new Foo();

public void ShowStatus()
{
    string status = foo.Bar();
    //change the string value to each while loop
}
```

In this case, the expected output would be to update the string to each loop without the method having to end.

Comment: You need to use [events](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_events.htm).

Comment: It probably is updating it, however because its running on the UI thread it is blocking the code behind the scenes that allows it to show you the value changed.  Then taking into account you never tell it to update the bar.. Events are a good way to handle "onValueChange"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refactor your method to run asynchronously and pass an `IProgress` object to it:

```
public async Task ShowStatusAsync(IProgress<StatusProgress> progress)
{
  ...
  progress?.Report(new StatusProgress(...));
}
```

Here is some further information about that pattern:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event in your `Foo` class:

```
public delegate void ProgressEventHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);
public event ProgressEventHandler Progress;
```

...and then subscribe to this event from your other class:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Progress += (sender, e) => { /* Do something */ };
```

...but you'll need to write a lot of code, including the class `ProgressEventArgs`, and going async with the `Progress` generic class as suggested by @Stefan is probably easier.