# Show loader during initialize component loads wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with utility where i am installing files for one of application. I need to show loader during installation process.

**Form Constructor:**

```
  public OMSUpdate(string isClientSetup)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadandInstallFiles();//Need to initiate loader before this call and close after this call.
    }
```

In LoadandInstallFiles Method i am getting latest files from database and placing them in directories.
How i can do this. I already searched and checked links which are available on web but most of them using button click event. I need this just on InitializeComponent.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you edit the `LoadandInstallFiles` method? If so, please try this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573323/5295692

Comment: Actually in this method i am getting latest files from database and placing them on directories.

Comment: You should not run code does any substantial work in a view's constructor. Certainly not any that can error. You should move your code to an event like loaded instead. Preferably into a viewmodel. Also. Is your problem showing a loading animation or doing something with files? Or something else?